# Hiding the Previous Sprite

Tags: android, coronasdk

I'm new in creating Android games using corona and I'm trying to create a character that move's using the codes below. My problem is it leaves the sprite mark when moving. How can I hide or erase the previous sprite mark?

```
local start = display.newImage( "start.png" )
physics.addBody(start, {friction = 1.0, density = 1.0})
start.bodyType = "static"
start.x = field.contentWidth/2 - 40
start.y = field.contentHeight/2
start.isFixedRotation = "true"

function spriteup()
    personSpriteSheet = sprite.newSpriteSheet("back.png", 30, 45)
    personSprite = sprite.newSpriteSet(personSpriteSheet, 1, 4)
    sprite.add(personSprite, "test", a, a, 1000, 1)
    person = sprite.newSprite(personSprite)
    person.x = start.x + 2
    person.y = start.y
    person:prepare("test")

end

function moveup(self, event)
    self:applyForce(0, -15, event.x, event.y)
    spriteup()
    if a == 4 then
        a = 0
    end
    a =a + 1
end 

local function listenerup(event)
    if event.phase == "began" then
    start.bodyType = "dynamic"
    start.alpha = 0
    if a == 4 then
        a = 0
    end
    a = a + 1
    start.enterFrame = moveup
    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", start)
    else
        Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", start)
        start.bodyType = "static"
    end
    return true
end
up:addEventListener( "touch", listenerup)
```

any thoughts will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried .remove( person ) ?